# Normalize numbers from 1-.0000X to 1 - 0.0X?

Tags: math

I have range of numbers that range from 1 - 0.00000X . Most are small numbers like 0.000823. How can I map them so that they are closer in range ? I used sqrt method but any other suggestions ?

**Update**

Example 
Numbers between 1-0.1 I don't have problem with them . My problem with numbers below 0.1. I need to bring them closer to 0.1.

- .00004 -> 0.0004 or 0.004
- 0.023 -> 0.05 or 0.09

Comment: I can imagine tons of ways of mapping these values; which would be most appropriate would depend on things like what they represent & how they are meant to be used.  For example, what's wrong w/ using sqrt?

Comment: I want the number to be in range 1-0 . My problem is that I have a lot of low numbers like 0.000023. sqrt shrinks them well but I need something better. For example numbers that have 4 or more 0,  .0000X or 0.00000000X I would like to map them to 1 thing which is smaller also, maybe 0.000X or even 0.0X

Comment: Again, define "better".  For example, we could map all numbers above, say 0.1 to 1, and then spread out those below across 0-0.99 evenly.

Comment: Numbers between 0.1 and 0.9 I don't need to change them much . I need to shrink more what is below 0.1 to bring them closer

Comment: Well if `sqrt` is not good enough, use `pow(x, 0.25)` or `pow(x, 0.125)`. Same thing basically, but a lot steeper. For example, `pow(0.000001, 0.125) = 0.17782`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Have you tried logarithms?](http://xkcd.com/451/)

If your numbers satisfy `eps < x <= 1`, the function

`y = 1 - C*log(x)` where `C = 1/-log(eps)`

will map the numbers to a range 0..1. If the range isn't required, only that the numbers are close together, you can drop the scale factor.

Edit:
This can be expressed without a subtraction of course.

`y = 1 + C*log(x)` where `C = 1/log(eps)`

For example, with an epsilon of 0.0000000001 (10^-10), you get C = -0.1 and:

```
0.0000000001 => 0
0.000000001  => 0.1
0.00000001   => 0.2
...
0.1          => 0.9
1            => 1
```

Edit: If you don't want to change the range from 0.1 ... 1.0 but only smaller numbers, then just scale the range from 0 ... 0.1. This can be done by multiplying x with 10 before the function is applied, and divide again by 10 after. Of course in this case use the scale function only if the value is less than 0.1.

Comment: 1- log (x) , will give more weight to low numbers . For example .0003 will be higher than .3

Comment: Yes of course. So does `sqrt`, which you gave as example, so what?

Comment: But subtracting make the reverse

Comment: Thats because a logarithm of a number smaller than 1 is negative. I add a version without subtraction which produces exactly the same result.

Comment: I am very disappointed that your first sentence wasn't "[have you tried logarithms?](http://xkcd.com/451/)".

Answer (score 0):

Well, a simple way would be to calculate the minimal one (say, `1-t`), and remap the segment `[1-t, 1]` to `[0, 1]`. The mapping function could be linear:

```
xnew = (xold - 1) / t + 1
```

(of course `t = 1 - min value`)

Comment: I need the mapping to be between 0 and 1 no -

Comment: @tnaser: Yes, the mapping will be between 0 and 1. Try it :-)

Comment: If number 0.002 and min 0.00005, this will give -0.499 ? . used (X-1)/ (1-min+1)

Comment: @tnaser: no, your parentheses are wrong. you need `(X-1)/(1-min)+1`

Comment: It doesn't change numbers much. Please check the example above for update